# Installing Pip for PyPy on Windows

Tags: windows, pip, pypy, tqdm

Can someone help me out with this issue. I am trying to install Pip on Windows to use with PyPy, but I am somehow unable to do it.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
C:\>pypy3 --version
Python 3.10.13 (fc59e61cfbff, Jan 14 2024, 16:27:58)
[PyPy 7.3.15 with MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

C:\>pypy3 -m pip install tqdm
C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe: No module named pip (to install pip, you need to run once "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe -m ensurepip")

C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)"\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe -m ensurepip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: c:\Users\karlv\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgk258d80
Processing c:\users\karlv\appdata\local\temp\tmpgk258d80\setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\karlv\appdata\local\temp\tmpgk258d80\pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-24.0 setuptools-69.2.0

C:\>pypy3 -m pip install tqdm
C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe: No module named pip (to install pip, you need to run once "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe -m ensurepip")
```

I also tried installing the `get-pip.py` file into the source files as well:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\get-pip.py"
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Using cached setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (821 kB)
Using cached wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-23.0.1 setuptools-65.5.0 wheel-0.43.0
```

Still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any other PYTHON* environment variables set? What does: `set PY` show?

Comment: ``set PY`` seems to be a Linux command and didn't work. Using ``py -0`` or ``py --list`` gave me this: 

`C:\>py --list 
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.10-64 
`

I have PyPy installed from source in a separate location, but I have added it to PATH so I can use it on the command line as well.

Comment: Are you using PowerShell or cmd.exe? In cmd.exe `set PY` should show you any environment variables that start with PY. I would recommend using cmd.exe, I am not sure what tricks PowerShell plays.

Comment: I am using cmd.exe, It just says `Environment variable PY not defined`. How can I define it then?

Comment: No need to define it, I wanted to make sure it was __not__ defined. I assume if you run `C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypy3.exe -m pip install tqdm` directly it also fails?

What happens if you put PyPy into a directory with no spaces in the name instead of where it currently is?

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\PyPy\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\bin` to PATH? As your command pip should be installed to the path of `bin`.

Comment: `PATH` is useful for scripts, but not for Python modules. The OP has problem with `pip` module, not `pip` script. `pypy3 -m pip` <- here `pypy3` is the interpreter and `pip` is a module, not a script.

Comment: For clarification, I have already added PyPy to path. Hence why I shared that the command ``pypy3 --version`` works without errors and doesn't give an error along the lines that it "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". 

On Linux it was easy to install pip for PyPy, but I don't understand why I can't do the same for Windows. It could be some sort of PATH issue bc I have Python3.10 installed as well and maybe when I use the ``ensurepip`` it still somehow defaults to Python3.10 not PyPy.